# explore_lite does not work with cartographer

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, exploration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As mentioned in https://github.com/hrnr/m-explore/issues/28
there is a bug where explore_lite does not work with cartographer.

I tried to modify code of explore_lite, but it wasn't successful.
Does anyone have an idea how to fix?

Which other package I can use with cartographer to autonomously explore map?
What do you do to autonomously explore map?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/352553/explore_lite-does-not-work-with-cartographer/) by [tonglliyoon](https://answers.ros.org/users/55005/tonglliyoon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2020-05-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[fork](https://github.com/c650/m-explore) of explore_lite that solves this bug.

---

Originally posted by [tonglliyoon](https://answers.ros.org/users/55005/tonglliyoon/) with karma: 11 on 2020-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1